# Showing that a set is a linearly independant subset of a 2 degree polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image]

(Doing part (ii) of this question)

What i did was  find the wronskian determinant:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 &  t-t^2 \\
    0 & 1-2t \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

So determinant is 1(1-2t) = 1- 2t which does not equal zero, therefore subset is linearly independant.

Would this be the correct method?

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the standard basis $\{1,t,t^2\}$ the given vectors have coordinates

- $1=1\cdot 1+0\cdot t + 0 \cdot t^2$ that is $$(1,0,0)$$
- $t(1-t)=t-t^2=0\cdot 1+1\cdot t + (-1) \cdot t^2$ that is $$(0,1,-1)$$

and they are linearly independent.

Comment: So is my method wrong?

Comment: @RandyRogers It seems correct but in linear algebra context the method is not often used. Indeed you might encounter cases where the wronskian can't be used and you need the general method by vectors.